# How to give a specific intent response in Amazon Lex based on an earlier response?

Tags: amazon-web-services, chatbot, alexa-skills-kit, amazon-lex, amazon-connect

I have an initial intent used to classify the user ie Intent1 "I Need help" with a 1 slot (Slot 1) asking "what type of user are you? "  The options are "userType1", "UserType2" and UserType3".

following this, with Amazon connect I have a a GetUserInput with multiple inputs. i.e. "What do you need help with?", with lots of intents new intents e.g Intent 2 "Shoes", Intent 3 "socks" Intent 4 "sandals.

Within Intent 2, I want to give a specific text response, Based on the answer to Slot1. the intents are different?

Answer (score 0):

You have to manage context of the conversation to be able to take actions based on previous responses.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lex/latest/dg/context-mgmt.html

Basically in the first intent, based on the slot value you have to store it in session attributes, in the next intent you will check the value and generate the response.

Do check the OrderFlowers Blueprint Lambda function and [this link](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lex/latest/dg/gs-bp-details-after-lambda.html). Notice that once the user gives the slot value of `FlowerType` it sets the price as session attribute.
[image]

Hope it helps, let me know if you have further doubts

Comment: Hi, 
thank you for your response. are you able to elaborate on this. I have read through the documentation attached but not sure how it applies within my scenario. (As i am using this in conjunction with Amazon Connect) .  I have given more detail above